# ¿Puedo utilizar next js solo en algunos componentes de react?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

Buen día, quisiera implementar next js para aplicar server side rendering en react, pero antes de implementar quisiera si se puede aplicar server side rendering solo a algunos componentes de mi proyecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta es si, pero no. Puedes hacer SSR (Server Side Rendering) de algún página específica, no de cada componente. Next.js usa Static generation por defecto y recomiendan usar SSR sólo cuando sea absolutamente necesario. Por ejemplo, un dashboard que se actualiza en tiempo real y no puede ser *pre-rendereado*.

Para usar SSR de una página necesitas exportar una función que se llama `getServerSideProps`. Esta función será llamada en cada petición.
To use Server-side Rendering for a page, you need to export an async function called getServerSideProps.

Este es el ejemplo de su [documentación oficial](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering):

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

function Page({ data }) {
  // Render data...
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Pide datos de una API externa
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../data`)
  const data = await res.json()

  // Manda los datos como props
  return { props: { data } }
}

export default Page
```